# hashcat : Depends: libminizip1t64 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: linux, package, apt, parrot-os, hashcat

I am using Parros OS [parrotos](/questions/tagged/parrotos). Recently I update my apt packages by this comment: `sudo apt update` and it shows some packages telling me that, These packages it not needed anymore. I uninstalled this packages manually. Then I got this:

```
$sudo apt full-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  hashcat
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I tried `sudo apt install hashcat` but it shows:

```
└──╼ $sudo apt install hashcat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hashcat : Depends: libminizip1t64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to fix the broken package: `sudo apt-get -f install` but it shows:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```